# Ploly graph in Shiny application is a flat line instead of working scatter plot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am working with shiny to create a drop down box where you can select an item.  When that item is selected a plotly graph is displayed.  When I run the plotly graph by itself I get a nice looking scatter plot, but when I run it in the shiny application I get a straight line on each of the three items.

This is the plotly code that works when ran by itself:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(df1, x = ~time, y = ~item1, color = ~item1) 
%>% add_lines(name = ~"item1")
```

This is what the dataset looks like with 4 columns and 26949 rows:

```
      time                      item1    item2    item3
1     2018-04-09 00:00:06        615       NA       NA
2     2018-04-09 00:00:08         NA      465       NA
3     2018-04-09 00:00:08         NA       NA       NA
4     2018-04-09 00:00:10         NA       NA      422
5     2018-04-09 00:00:13         NA       NA       NA
6     2018-04-09 00:00:21        522       NA      385
7     2018-04-09 00:00:25         NA       NA       NA
....  ....                       ....     ....     ...
26949 2018-04-09 23:59:59        323       NA      200
```

The Shiny code is as follows:

```
#Import libraries
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

# Define UI for the application
ui <- bootstrapPage(

selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
            label = "Select Item:",
            choices = c("item1", "item2", "item3"),
            selected = "item1"),

plotlyOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "300px")

)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

#Import data
df = read.csv("item_list.csv")

output$main_plot <- renderPlotly({

#Plotly graph
plot_ly(df, x = ~time, y = ~input$n_breaks, color = ~input$n_breaks) %>%
  add_lines(name = ~input$n_breaks)
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For the most part this code works but the graph is messed up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the `plot_ly` function as:

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~time, 
        y = df[, input$n_breaks], 
        color = df[, input$n_breaks]) %>%
        add_lines(name = ~input$n_breaks)
```

Or a bit shorter as:

```
plot_ly(x = df[, "time"], 
        y = df[, input$n_breaks], 
        color = df[, input$n_breaks]) %>%
        add_lines(name = ~input$n_breaks)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm @DJack .  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If you think it solved your problem, consider accepting the answer to close the question (stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Just accepted it.  Still kind of new at this, thank you for reminding me!